# Finding all paths/walks of given length in a networkx graph

Tags: python, path, networkx, shortest

I'm using networkx and trying to find all the walks with length 3 in the graph, specifically the paths with three edges. I tried to find some information about the algorithms in the networkx documentation but I could only find the algorithms for the shortest path in the graph. Can I find a length of a path trough specific nodes, for example a path trough nodes 14 -> 11 -> 12 -> 16 if the shortest path is 14 -> 15 -> 16? Here's an image of a graph for an example:

[image: example graph]

Comment: @msw I'm guessing you meant [all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length.html)? Your link goes to the threading docs

Comment: Yeah all_pairs_dijsktra_path_length would do the trick if I want to find out how many paths in graph have length of 3 or lower, but I would like to get the sum of weights of the edges in the path and only for paths with length of 3 not lower. Same thing works for all_pairs_dijkstra_path, you get all the paths of length 3 or lower not just the ones with the length 3.

Comment: Just to be clear, `a-b-a-b` wouldn't be a length 3 path, would it?  I'm assuming you are going to ignore cycles?

Comment: By definition path is a walk with different edges and nodes, cycles are something inbetween because their starting node is equal to their ending node. If I had to choose I would ignore cycles.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simplest version (another version is below which I think is faster):

```
def findPaths(G,u,n):
    if n==0:
        return [[u]]
    paths = [[u]+path for neighbor in G.neighbors(u) for path in findPaths(G,neighbor,n-1) if u not in path]
    return paths
```

This takes a network `G` and a node `u` and a length `n`.  It recursively finds all paths of length n-1 starting from neighbors of `u` that don't include `u`.  Then it sticks `u` at the front of each such path and returns a list of those paths.

Note, each path is an ordered list.  They all start from the specified node.  So for what you want, just wrap a loop around this:

```
allpaths = []
for node in G:
    allpaths.extend(findPaths(G,node,3))
```

Note that this will have any `a-b-c-d` path as well as the reverse `d-c-b-a` path.

If you find the "list comprehension" to be a challenge to interpret, here's an equivalent option:

```
def findPathsNoLC(G,u,n):
    if n==0:
        return [[u]]
    paths = []
    for neighbor in G.neighbors(u):
        for path in findPathsNoLC(G,neighbor,n-1):
            if u not in path:
                paths.append([u]+path)
    return paths
```

For optimizing this, especially if there are many cycles, it may be worth sending in a set of disallowed nodes.  At each nested call it would know not to include any nodes from higher up in the recursion.  This would work instead of the `if u not in path` check.  The code would be a bit more difficult to understand, but it would run faster.

```
def findPaths2(G,u,n,excludeSet = None):
    if excludeSet == None:
        excludeSet = set([u])
    else:
        excludeSet.add(u)
    if n==0:
        return [[u]]
    paths = [[u]+path for neighbor in G.neighbors(u) if neighbor not in excludeSet for path in findPaths2(G,neighbor,n-1,excludeSet)]
    excludeSet.remove(u)
    return paths
```

Note that I have to add `u` to `excludeSet` before the recursive call and then remove it before returning.