# Simple path queries on large graphs

Tags: data-mining, networkx, jung, spark-graphx, large-data

I have a question about large graph data. Suppose that we have a large graph with nearly 100 million edges and around 5 million nodes, in this case what is the best graph mining platform that you know of that can give all simple paths of lengths <=k (for k=3,4,5) between any two given nodes. The main concern is the speed of getting those paths. Another thing is that the graph is directed, but we would like the program to ignore the directions when computing the paths but still return the actually directed edges once it spots those paths.

For instance:

a -> c <- d -> b is a valid path between nodes 'a' and 'b' of length 3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you think that I can handle this operation with NetworkX python network package by using a super computer? Thanks

Comment: What about graph-tool package? Does anyone  have knowledge on it? Is it the best tool for the thing that I mentioned above? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a way to do it in networkx.  It's roughly based on the solution I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095646/finding-all-paths-walks-of-given-length-in-a-networkx-graph).  I'm assuming that `a->b` and `a<-b` are two distinct paths you want.  I'm going to return this as a list of lists.  Each sublist is the (ordered) edges of a path.

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools

def getPaths(G,source,target, maxLength, excludeSet=None):
    #print source, target, maxLength, excludeSet
    if excludeSet== None:
        excludeSet = set([source])
    else:
        excludeSet.add(source)# won't allow a path starting at source to go through source again.
    if maxLength == 0:
        excludeSet.remove(source)
        return []
    else:
        if G.has_edge(source,target):
            paths=[[(source,target)]]
        else:
            paths = []
        if G.has_edge(target,source):
            paths.append([(target,source)])
        #neighbors_iter is a big iterator that will give (neighbor,edge) for each successor of source and then for each predecessor of source.

        neighbors_iter = itertools.chain(((neighbor,(source,neighbor)) for neighbor in G.successors_iter(source) if neighbor != target),((neighbor,(neighbor,source)) for neighbor in G.predecessors_iter(source) if neighbor != target))

        #note that if a neighbor is both a predecessor and a successor, it shows up twice in this iteration.  

        paths.extend( [[edge] + path for (neighbor,edge) in neighbors_iter if neighbor not in excludeSet for path in getPaths(G,neighbor,target,maxLength-1,excludeSet)] )

        excludeSet.remove(source) #when we move back up the recursion, don't want to exclude this source any more

        return paths

G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3),(1,3),(1,4),(3,4),(4,3)])

print getPaths(G,1,3,2)

>[[(1, 3)], [(1, 2), (2, 3)], [(1, 4), (4, 3)], [(1, 4), (3, 4)]]
```

I would expect that by modifying the dijkstra algorithm in networkx you'll arrive at a more efficient algorithm (note that the dijkstra algorithm has a cutoff, but by default it's only going to return the shortest path, and it's going to follow edge direction).

Here's an alternative version of the whole paths.extend thing:
paths.extend( [[edge] + path for (neighbor,edge) in neighbors_iter if neighbor not in excludeSet for path in getPaths(G,neighbor,target,maxLength-1,excludeSet) if len(path)>0 ] )

Comment: The code above gives also the paths that don't have either source node or target node. However, I need the paths that contains source node and target node.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  The example I gave asked for all paths from 1 to 3 of length at most 2.  All of the paths it returned started at 1 and ended at 3 ignoring direction of edge.

Comment: I tried it with a bit bigger graph but some of the paths don't have target node even though they satisfy the given path length.

Comment: Corrected it.  Bug was related to the fact that in one place I was returning `[[]]` rather than `[]`.  So it was returning a list containing an empty path and then gladly adding edges to the empty path thinking that it was a path that got to the target.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Gephi](http://gephi.github.io/) easy to handle and learn.

If you found it though [Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/) will do your requirement with a little bit of coding.

Comment: Actually I know Gephi but I am looking for something else like a platform(such as NetworkX, Jung, Pajek, etc.) that I can use as a graph mining API to customize my requirements.