# Extract routes from a given data set and visualize them with networkx

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, networkx

Given is a DataFrame with pairs of start and end locations in chronological order.

Example:

1. a-b
2. g-d
3. b-g
4. .....

The goal is to create a "networkx" map to visualize all the routes with more than 2 nodes.  Like this: A --> B --> G and so on...

I thought i could probably do this by sub setting the df to where end location == start location.

How would one subset the dataset and loop through it until there is no more end location == start location?

Comment: I think maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095646/finding-all-paths-walks-of-given-length-in-a-networkx-graph) would help

Answer (score 0):

I can propose this code

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'start': ['a', 'g', 'b', 'd', 'b'], 'end': ['b', 'd', 'g', 'a', 'e']})

G = nx.Graph()
def add_path(elemnt):
    global G
    G.add_edge(elemnt.start, elemnt.end)

df.apply(add_path, axis=1)
nx.draw(G, with_labels = True)
```

hope it helps